# Getting the last value from a sequence in SQL and insert it into another table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, node.js

I have 2 tables, which were created by executing the following (keep in mind that every query is executed through on node.js, i.e., connection.execute('select....') ):

```
create table User(userid int not null, name varchar(50) not null, primary key(userid));
create table Random(userid int not null, random int, primary key (userid), foreign key (userid) references User(userid) );
```

I also added a sequence to auto increment the userid:

```
create sequence userid_seq;

create or replace trigger userid_bir
before insert on User
for each row

begin 
   select userid_seq.nextval
   into :new.userid
   from dual;
end;
/
```

Now, I have a process whereby after I insert a new user, that user's id is inserted immediately into Random. I browsed through Stackoverflow and came up with:

```
insert into User(name) values('John');
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert into Random(userid, random) values( last_id, 2);
```

However, I got the following error:

```
SP2-0735: unknown SET option beginning "@last_id"
```

Any ideas?

My other concern is that if there are 2 computers trying to insert 2 users (in total) at the same time, the last_id value (or MAX userid value) might mess up. That is, the server might be executing:

```
insert into User(name) values('John'); ## from Person A
insert into User(name) values('Brian'); ## from Person B
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); ## from Person A, say it's set to 1
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); ## from Person B, say it's set to 2
insert into Random(userid, random) values( last_id, 2); ## from Person A
insert into Random(userid, random) values( last_id, 2); ## from Person B, error: duplicate values?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably MySQL syntax. In Oracle you can use [RETURNING INTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) clause.

```
declare
    last_id number;
begin
    insert into user(name) values('Abcd') 
    returning userid into last_id;

    insert into Random(userid, random) values( last_id, 2);
    commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: i tried yours and got the following error: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (WEEROCKS.SYS_C003995) violated - parent key
not found
ORA-06512: at line 6

Comment: There must be some other foreign key reference to some table. You need to look where WEEROCKS.SYS_C003995 constraint is referring to.

Comment: how can i see what it's referring to?

Comment: You can check the [ALL_CONSTRAINTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm) AND [ALL_CONS_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1035.htm) views.
Search for SYS_C003995 constraint name in ALL_CONSTRAINTS and find the R_CONSTRAINT_NAME column. Then check this value in ALL_CONS_COLUMNS to find which table and column it is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

`userid_seq.currval` will return the most recent value returned for the sequence in the current session.  So you can

```
INSERT INTO random( userid, random )
  VALUES( user_id_seq.currval, 2 );
```

If you want to have the value in a local variable

```
DECLARE
  l_userid user.user_id%type;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO user(name)
    VALUES( 'John' )
    RETURNING userid 
         INTO l_userid;
  INSERT INTO random( userid, random )
    VALUES( l_userid, 2 );
END;
```

Comment: I tried using currval, but apparently it can't be used through node.js? Since i'm executing these queries through connection.execute('query')

Comment: What does "can't be used" mean?  Do you get an error?  If so, what error?  Are you certain that both calls are in the same physical database session?